# Redirect http to https and also no-www to www

Tags: apache

I want to redirect the following:

`http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

`http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

`https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

'www.example.com' to https://www.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these `mod_rewrite` rules into an `.htaccess` file at the root of your site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Note that you will need the `mod_rewrite` module enabled. Also, you may need to adjust the `.htaccess` permissions/overrides in your Apache config.

Comment: In my testing it works for all the cases you've listed. Which cases are not working exactly? What is your full .htaccess, as other rules could be affecting these.

Comment: I  Am using windows with 2 virtual server 80 and 443 configured in the http-ssl.conf where should I add the above rule??

Comment: I typically use the .htaccess file. I was under the assumption you've gotten this far already. I need to update my answer. (Answer updated.)

Comment: I have no clue as in how to access the  .htaccess currently am adding the rules httpd-ssl config file

Comment: That's fine. In httpd-ssl config you only need to add the `www` rule. You will need to add both rules to http (non-ssl) config (I think this is the part you're missing).

Comment: Thank you Bitwise Creative.